# добавить данные в массив, который отправляется ajax запросом, на сервер (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, массивы

добрый день. Есть данные

```
data = Array
(
    [ltype] => Узнать 1
    [goal] => uznat_01_now
    [thanx] => thanx1
    [phone] => +7 (111) 222 11 11
    [action] => send
    [formorder] => form-0
)
```

которые отправляются  `ajax`

```
    $.ajax({
      url:'index.php',
      type: "POST",
      data : data,
      success: function(data){
console.log(data);
      }
    });
```

К  массиву `data` надо еще добавить данные из `utm` меток

```
var utm = new {
  type_traffic: sbjs.get.current.typ,
  utm_source: sbjs.get.current.src,
  utm_medium: sbjs.get.current.mdm,
  utm_campaign: sbjs.get.current.cmp,
  utm_content: sbjs.get.current.cnt,
  utm_term: sbjs.get.current.trm
};
```

Мне понадобилось добавлять элементы в ассоциативный массив. На JavaScript нет ассоциативных массивов. Теперь не могу найти аналог функции push(). Подскажите, если кто-нибудь знает. Спасибо.

Comment: тут синтаксическая ошибка: `var utm = new {`, `data` который приходит это все-таки массив или объект?

Comment: передается на сервер ассоциативный массив

Answer (score 1):

```js
let utm = {
    type_traffic: 'type_traffic',
    utm_source: 'utm_source',
    utm_medium: 'utm_medium',
    utm_campaign: 'utm_campaign',
    utm_content: 'utm_content',
    utm_term: 'utm_term',
  },
  data = { // В JS - объекты с именованными ключами НЕ могут быть массивами, так что это объект. P. S. new не нужен с коротким синтаксисом {}
    ltype: 'Узнать 1',
    goal: 'uznat_01_now',
    thanx: 'thanx1',
    phone: '+7 (111) 222 11 11',
    action: 'send',
    formorder: 'form-0',
  };

Object.keys(utm).forEach(e =>
  data[e] = utm[e] // Вставляем по ключам
  // Массив - [1, 2, 3]
  // Array.prototype.push - отправляет элемент в массив - arr.push('some')
);

console.info(data);
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ.... но данные пример с ошибкой и сейчас не совсем понимаю как ее исправить

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, пример рабочий, объект заполнен. Что не работает? P. S. Возможно в старых браузерах код не будет работать, ибо старые, сам код рабочий.

Answer (score 0):

В качестве ассоциативного массива в JavaScript выступает объект.

Добавить в него новый элемент можно двумя способами: указав ключ элемента через точку или в квадратных скобках.

```
data.type_traffic = utm.type_traffic
// либо
const key = 'type_traffic' 
data[key] = utm.[key]
```

Второй способ обычно используется, когда в качестве ключа требуется использовать значение переменной.

В данной же задаче, похоже, будет удобнее не присваивать ключи по одному, а слить два объекта в один. Для этого можно воспользоваться методом [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
Object.assign(data, utm)
```

Или же, если не нужно модифицировать исходный объект `data`:

```
const result = Object.assign({}, data, utm);
```

Следует отметить, что метод поддерживается не всем браузерами. Для лучшей поддержки стоит подключить [полифилл](https://github.com/sindresorhus/object-assign).